# Spark Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: [5.52] failure: ``union'' expected but `('

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

The below query is working against db but giving error as:

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: [5.52] failure: ``union'' expected but
>   `('"sum(case when action = 'purchase' then 1 else 0 end) as purchase_count,

Code :

```
val activityByProduct = SQLContext.sql("""
    SELECT
        product,
        timestamp_hour
        sum(case when action = 'purchase' then 1 else 0 end) as purchase_count,
        |sum(case when action = 'add_to_cart' then 1 else 0 end) as add_to_cart,
        |sum(case when action = 'page_view' then 1 else 0 end) as page_view
    |from activity
    |group by product,timestamp_hour """)
```

May someone please help me, if i am missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing coma after « timestamp_hour ».

```
SELECT
       product,
       timestamp_hour,<— HERE
        sum(case when action = 'purchase' then 1 else 0 end) as purchase_count,
```

Also you should remove all « | » characters from you query